# How to name dict variables imported from a CSV file ? in Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I know how to import dictionary type variables from a CSV file like:

```
code;description;price
c321;white glove;52
d654;orange hat;65
d658;red scarf;85
```

with this code:

```
import csv

inputfile = open("myfile.csv")
reader_dict = csv.DictReader(inputfile, delimiter=';')

catalog=[]

for line in reader_dict:
    catalog.append(line)
```

when I need to use a dict variable included in the list variable "catalog" I have to use a "for loop" like:

```
for item in catalog:
    if item["code"]=="code I am looking for":
        print ("now can I use the item am interested in!!")
```

Is this elegant ?

Othewise is there a way to give names to each dict variable included in the "catalog" list ?

The name could be one value associated with a key in the dictionary (e.g. the value associated with the "code" key), I would like to automatically create variable like:

```
c321 = {'code': 'c321', 'descritpion': 'white glove', 'price':'52'}
```

If this is possible I could easily use a variable with his name instead of using a "for loop" each time.

Comment: @martineau thanks: I have edited the question, I hope is more lear now.

Comment: Yes, it can be done, but read [_Why you don't want to dynamically create variables_](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html) first. At a simpler level, how are you going to know in advance to write code to reference variable `c321`?

Comment: It is certainly possible to create such variables, the question is, do you really want to? It is rather un-pythonic, IMHO. Also you would probably have to keep track of all the (variable-)names you created for later use. My suggestion would be to use a (nested) dict, e.g. make your catalog a dictionary and add the records from your csv file with the name of your choice as key. Then you could access it like `catalog['c321']['description']` -> `'white glove'`.

Comment: Another viable possibility is to make it so you could reference the value of items in the catalog list using something like `item.code`, `item.description`, etc. Would that be helpful?

Comment: Your question _is_ different now, however even with your edit, you would have to reference the components of the variable like: `c321['code']`, `c321['descritpion']`, etc -- so I'm still not completely clear about what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment at OP:

> It is certainly possible to create such variables, the question is, do
>   you really want to? It is rather un-pythonic, IMHO. Also you would
>   probably have to keep track of all the (variable-)names you created
>   for later use. My suggestion would be to use a (nested) dict, e.g.
>   make your catalog a dictionary and add the records from your csv file
>   with the name of your choice as key.

```
import csv

catalog = {}
with open("myfile.csv") as inputfile:
  rows = csv.DictReader(inputfile, delimiter=';')
  for row in rows:
    key = row['code']
    catalog[key] = row

print( catalog["some_code"]["description"] )
```

Or incorporating **martineau**s suggestion: 
(**EDIT1:** tweaked to improve elegance)
(**EDIT2:** fixed error, so that it actually works as intended)

```
import csv
import collections

catalog = {}
with open("myfile.csv", 'rb') as inputfile:
  row_iterator = csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter=';')
  Record = collections.namedtuple('Record', next(row_iterator))
  # EDIT2: each row is a list here, so we have to use the columnindex to specify the key
  catalog = {row[0]: Record._make(row) for row in row_iterator}    


print( catalog["some_code"].description )
```

Comment: can you explain me how   next(rows)   works,  please ?

Comment: @Thermophilus: the `next(iterator)` buildin-function calls the `__next__` function on the given iterator. I recommend that you read the pertinent sections of the python documentation. [Iterator](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-iterator), iterable, generator, list comprehension and dict comprehension are important features of the python language and well worth the time understanding them.

Comment: @Thermophilus: Regarding the error message you got: I assumed `csv.reader()` would return a list, but it returns an interator instead. And iterators cannot be indexed ('iterator[0]' does not work).

Comment: The `catalog` dictionary created in the second block of code, will have one entry in it `catalog['code']` whose value will be a list of all records read from the file. Therefore the last line will raise a `KeyError` exception. I doubt that's what the OP really wants. Also, calling the `csv.reader` object created `rows` is somewhat disingenuous (since I know how it ended up that way). I also suggest you read and follow the [_PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code_](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) particularly with code you post here on SO. Maybe you ought to test it, too.

Comment: @martineau: True enough. I mixed up the differences between `csv.DictReader` and `csv.reader`. As for the variable name, you have a point there, but I wanted to avoid the generic `reader` and failed to come up with a suitable (and short) name at first. Regarding PEP8: the only thing off is the two space indent I'm using and that's because I'm tired of typing 12!! spaces for a level 2 indent. I find the SO markup syntax extremely tiresome (or perhaps I just don't know how to use it correctly).

Comment: `csv_reader` would be a less generic name. I get 4 spaces at a time in my editor by typing a single tab (although I can force a tab character to be inserted if I wish). It's also Python-aware and offers auto-completion and a number of other useful features, like jump to named function definition, etc. Perhaps you should consider upgrading your tools (or skills at configuring and using what you already have).

Comment: @martineau To clarify: My editor expands tabs too, the problem is that I sometimes post answers without having access to python (and the editor) at that time. And writing code in the SO edit box is difficult. But thats rather far OT, and this is probably not the right place.

Comment: When you do that perhaps you should add a disclaimer of "untested" somewhere. FWIW -- I'm not boasting, honest -- I noticed all the issues I've mentioned simply by reading your code...maybe you just need to slow down and spend a little more time crafting your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I meant in one of my comments:

```
import csv
import collections

with open("myfile.csv", 'rb') as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter=';')
    Record = collections.namedtuple('Record', next(reader))  # use header row
    catalog = [Record._make(row) for row in reader]

for item in catalog:
    print item.code, item.description, item.price
```

Output:

```
c321 white glove 52
d654 orange hat 65
d658 red scarf 85
```

Since`catalog`is still a`list`, a`for`loop is still required to sequentially access each of its elements, but accessing the fields of each one would now be a little less awkward.

**Update**

If you really want to avoid the`for`loop and know the codes in advance, you could do something like the following which creates a`catalog`dictionary keyed by the code value in the first field of each record with the rest of each rows's value mapped to field names in a nested`AttrDict`dictionary:

```
class AttrDict(dict):  # from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576972-attrdict
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttrDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self

with open("myfile.csv", 'rb') as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter=';')
    fields = next(reader)  # header row
    # row[0] is dict key with remaining values mapped to fieldnames
    catalog = {row[0]: AttrDict(zip(fields[1:], row[1:])) for row in reader}

print catalog
c321 = catalog['c321']
print 'c321:', repr(c321.description), int(c321.price)
```

Output:

```
{'c321': {'description': 'white glove', 'price': '52'},
 'd654': {'description': 'orange hat', 'price': '65'},
 'd658': {'description': 'red scarf', 'price': '85'}}
c321: 'white glove' 52
```

Comment: Quite elegant solution, I like the use of `next(reader)` to handle the header.

Comment: I have learnt that my ideas was bad. I have used the nested dict solution and it works. So do the nametuples method (that I didn't know) suggested by @martineau. But I can't get how the next(reader) part works :(. The version suggest by you give me an error:   Product = collections.namedtuple('Product', rows[0])
TypeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: I love `namedtuple`s. If anything I overuse them, but I still wouldn't have thought to use them here. Great answer!

Comment: @AdamSmith the use of namedtuples in combination with reading csv data is actually one of the examples used in the namedtuples documentation.

Comment: @Adam Smith: A potential downside to using `namedtuple`s is that, unlike the list of items natively returned by a `csv.reader`, they're immutable. One possible workaround would be to use an add-on module like [`namedlist`](https://bitbucket.org/ericvsmith/namedlist) although I've never tried it. There's also an [`attrdict`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/attrdict/1.2.0) module which lets you do the same kind of things with dictionaries -- which are mutable -- so could be another alternative when used with the values returned from a `csv.DictReader`.